# Handling forms with many fields

Tags: ajax, yii, jeditable, flyweight-pattern

I have a very `large webform` that is the center of my `Yii` web application.  **The form actually consists of multiple html form elements, many of which are loaded via AJAX as needed.**

Because of the form's size and complexity, having multiple save or submit buttons isn't really feasible.  I would rather update each field in the database as it is edited by asynchrously AJAXing the new value to the server using jeditable or jeditable-like functionality.

Has anyone done anything like this?  In theory I'm thinking I could set up an `AJAX` endpoint and have each control pass in its name, its new value, and the `CRUD` operation you want to perform.  Then the endpoint can route the request appropriately based on some kind of map and return the product.  It just seems like someone has to have solved this problem before and I don't want to waste hours reinventing the wheel.

Your thoughts on architecture/implementation are appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In similar situation I decided to use [CActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm/) only for easy validation by Yii standarts (it can use Ajax validation), avoiding "`required`" attribute. And of course to keep logical structure of the form in a good view.

In common you're right. I manually used jQuery to generate AJAX-request (and any other actions) to the controller and process them there as you want.

So you may use CRUD in controller (analyzing parameters in requests) and in your custom jQuery (using group selectors), but you can hardly do it in `CActiveForm` directly (and it's good: compacting mustn't always beat the logic and structure of models).

Any composite solution with javascript in PHP will affect on flexibility of your non-trivial application.

Comment: And some specific practice. I had a situation with several large  forms rather like but only apart. So I created a main `CActiveForm` class and its several descendants. For `views` I created a `partial` one with a common part and included it with `renderPartial`. Of course javascript functions were separated in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it last night, I found this post:

[jQuery focus/blur on form, not individual inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049172/jquery-focus-blur-on-form-not-individual-inputs)

I'm using a modified version of this at the client to update each form via AJAX, instead of updating each field.  Each form automatically submits its data after a two seconds of inactivity.  The downside is the client might lose some data if their browser crashes, but the benefit is I can mostly use Yii's built-in controller actions and I don't have to write a lot of custom PHP.  Since my forms are small, but there are many of them, it seems to be working well so far.

Thanks Alexander for your excellent input and thanks Afnan for your help :)